How to center a table horizontally in an Azure DevOps Wiki page
I'm trying to horizontally center a table that is part of an Azure DevOps Wiki page. By centering I mean there should be the same amount of empty space on the left side of the table as on the right side. I tried is using the center tag as shown below but that doesn't work, i.e. the table is visible but still on the left side.
<center>

| My      | Table   |
|---------|---------|
| Value 1 | Value 2 |

</center>

I tried the same thing with an HTML table instead of the markdown one. However, that also does not work. Is it even possible to center a table?

This can work in the Wiki pages:
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 50%">

| My      | Table   |
|:---------:|:---------:|
| Value 1 | Value 2 |

</div>



Interesting, I actually tried putting it into a div but I only set the styles margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; without the width. With that approach it did not work. Adding the width makes it work BUT now I got the problem that my table sits within a block that occupies 50% of the entire width but within that block, the table is still left aligned. So I would need to try out different width percentages until the table occupies as much of the block as possible in order to really look like it is horizontally centered. Do you know a better way than using width?

@ackh, What do you mean about "BUT now I got the problem that my table sits within a block that occupies 50% of the entire width but within that block, the table is still left aligned."?

The div is set to have a width of 50% of the width of the page with 25% empty space on its left and right side. Inside that 50% the table is embedded. However, the width of the table depends on its content so 50% of the entire page might be not enough or it might be too much. That is the problem, i.e. if the table does not exactly use the entire 50% of the page, there is space left. And that space is located on its right side. So, with that approach the table can never be truly centered horizontally.

@ackh, Based on this documentation, the HTML tag "<center> </center>" should be the ideal way for your case.

@ackh, Not sure why the HTML tag "<center> </center>" does not work for tables. It might be an issue with the Wiki page of Azure DevOps. You can try to open a ticket on Developer Community to report this issue. The support engineers on Developer Community could help you report the issue to the appropriate produce team for further investigation if it is a defect of Wiki.

@ackh, In addition, the "<center> </center>" seems has been a deprecated HTML tag now. It might be a reason of why it does not work for tables.
